# Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c++

I'm writing a c++ program and I get this error after running it:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void Step(int dis,int len,int wid, int l=0,int w=0){

if(dis==0)
        cout<< l << "   "<< w << endl;


    Step(dis-wid,len,wid,l,w+1);
    Step(dis-len,len,wid,l+1,w);

}
int main(){

    Step(10,2,3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. If it's "how do I debug a core dump", tell us what debugger you like to use.

Comment: You get a core dump because your recursion never stops. You overflow the call stack

Comment: you forgot to write base condition to break recurssion.

Comment: Also you should probably use a loop instead of a recursive function, to avoid stack overflows.

Answer (score 3):

Every call to `Step` calls `Step` two more times, leading to a stack overflow. Actually, the second call to `Step` never happens since `Step` can never reach the end.

Answer (score 2):

`Step()` never ends. Add `return` in the if statement so the function can terminate.